# Change font-family of code block in Confluence

Tags: css, confluence

I'm trying to change the font-family of the code block in Confluence by adding this Space Tools -> Look and Feel -> Stylesheet:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed|Roboto:700|Roboto+Mono&display=swap');
.code { font-family: "Roboto Mono", monospace; }
```

If I inspect the computed CSS in the browser, it shows that it's using "Roboto Mono" for the font-family. However, visually, I know that it's not Roboto Mono but the default monospace font of the browser.

Comment: Can you please add a link to the page? Have you tried using inline styling using the developer tools in your browser and if so what was the outcome? Do you have multiple breakpoints in your CSS and do they all use the same code block? This issue may also be caused by another stylesheet doing an override. If that was to be the case you could re-order the stylesheets in the head of your HTML so that the stylesheet with the above code block loads last.

Comment: Yes, you're right. There was a style that was overriding the style I was using. I had to look into each class under the main class I was working on.

Comment: <code> is a tag, so you wouldn't treat it like a class and put a dot in front of it. Change `.code {}` to `code {}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this and it worked:

```
pre, code, .code, .code .container, .syntaxhighlighter div, .syntaxhighlighter code, .syntaxhighlighter a { font-family: "Roboto Mono", monospace; }
```